# Karma/Require.js cannot find files

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, requirejs, karma-runner

I am trying to write unit tests with karma under Require.js and AngularJS. I am taking https://github.com/tnajdek/angular-requirejs-seed as a starting point. When I build the project as-is, everything works fine.

```
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Windows 7): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.317 secs / 0.007 secs)
```

Now, I want to refer to a different version of the AngularJS scripts than is loaded by bower. (We have a production directory structure I cannot change.) I have the seed project in /scripts/angular-test and I want to refer to the AngularJS file not in the bower directory, but where it is in our system which is /scripts/angular/angular-dev-1.2.8.js.

I figured the first thing I'd need to do is modify the karma.conf.js file to point to a different root:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '../..',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
        files: [
            {pattern: 'angular-test/app/js/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'angular-test/app/js/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'angular-test/test/unit.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'angular-test/test/unit/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'angular-test/test/unit/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: 'angular-test/bower_components/**/*.js', included: false},
            // needs to be last http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/plus/requirejs.html
            'angular-test/test/main-test.js'
        ],
    autoWatch: true,
    LogLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    junitReporter: {
        outputFile: 'angular-test/test_out/unit.xml',
        suite: 'unit'
    }
  });
};
```

I changed all the other refs to have angular-test in their paths, such as in the main-test.js file:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        angular: '/base/angular-test/bower_components/angular/angular',
        angularRoute: '/base/angular-test/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
        angularMocks: '/base/angular-test/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks',
        text: '/base/angular-test/bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
        fixtures: '/base/angular-test/test/unit/fixtures'

    },
    baseUrl: '/base/angular-test/app/js',
...
```

Everything still works. Note that, at this point, I am still using all the same files that were in angular-requirejs-seed. However, the URLs in the browser do change; rather than

```
http://localhost:9876/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

the reference to angular.js is now

```
http://localhost:9876/base/angular-test/bower_components/angular/angular.js
```

So far so good. Now, I want to change that reference to angular.js. So I change it in main-test.js to

```
        angular: '/base/angular/angular-dev-1.2.8',
```

Now, it can no longer find angular - specifically, the browser tries to hit

```
http://localhost:9876/base/angular/angular-dev-1.2.8.js
```

just as one would expect, but it gets a 404 resulting in the karma error

```
ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for /base/angular/angular-dev-1.2.8.js!'
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Windows 7) ERROR
    Uncaught Error: Script error for: angular
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at d:/Gary/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.254 secs / 0 secs)
```

Given that the modified reference to "/base/angular-test/bower_components/angular/angular.js" works, I would expect this to work also, but it doesn't. The only thing I can think of is that for some reason the karma web server is restricting access to only the /base/angular-test subtree, though I cannot imagine why that would be.

Answer (score 0):

try `{pattern: 'angular-test/bower_components/**/*.js', included: false},` in your karma.conf.js file then in the main-test.js file mention:

```
shim: {

    'angular' : {'exports' : 'angular'},
    'angularMocks': {
        deps:['angular'],
        'exports':'angular.mock'
    },
    '<your App name>': {
        deps: ['angular'],
        'exports': '<your App name>'

}
```

I think you are getting error when requirejs fails to plug angular. When Chrome opens up, hit the debug button and then on the debugger, do inspect element and check if all the necessary files are being loaded in the `<body>`as well as `<head>`. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> So far so good. Now, I want to change that reference to angular.js. So I change it in main-test.js to
>
> angular: '/base/angular/angular-dev-1.2.8',
>
> Now, it can no longer find angular - specifically, the browser tries to hit
>
> localhost :9876/base/angular/angular-dev-1.2.8.js
>
> just as one would expect, but it gets a 404 resulting in the karma error

After you changed the reference in main-test.js and stuff started to fail, did you go back to your karma config file and make sure that the new file would be included? I forget to do that all the time so I always end up with those 404s.